# Using APIs within Django and how to display the data

Tags: django, rest, django-views

I am trying to test how to display API information within a view on my Django project. I know you may have to add some installed APIs into the settings INSTALLED APPS block.

This api is a simple geo one.

I am new to Django and new to using APIs within it. I have managed to get my app the way I need it using Youtube videos. But now I am on my own. I have many different view classes to display differents of my app.

The view below is the view Id like to place the data on.

is this how I would potentially do it? Then call {{ base }} within the HTHL to display it?

```py
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'clients/post_detail.html'

    def api_test(request):
        #  This is where the APIs are going to go.
        requests.get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
        data = response.json()
        return render(request, 'clients/post_detail.html', {
            'base': data['disclaimer']
        })
```

I am currently getting no errors within my app, but the country element isnt displaying.

I have tested the following in just a simple python file

```py
import requests
import json

response = requests.get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
data = response.json()

print(data['disclaimer'])
```

which gets the desired result. So I guess now my issue is...how do i get this into the HTML? So i can display the results from the API

Comment: I don't believe .json() is a valid Python method. Try json.loads(response) instead. You will need to 'import json' as a module at the top of your views file. This will serialize the json into a python dictionary which you can return as a context.

Comment: I'm afraid this didnt work. I have just updated my code and added a simple code block which works pulling from an API...now i just need to know how to put this into the html i have this `<h5>... {{ base }} ...</h5>` in my html page where i want to display the results

Comment: @wjh18 there's nothing wrong with `response.json()`, that's a perfectly valid method of the requests class.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes, that was my mistake, my apologies OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write like this:

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'clients/post_detail.html'

    def call_geo_api(self):
        #  This is where the APIs are going to go.
        response = requests.get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
        data = response.json()
        return data['disclaimer']

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostDetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['base'] = self.call_geo_api()
        return context
```

Here, I have overridden [**`get_context_data()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_context_data) method, which is responsible for sending context data from view to template.

Here I have changed your api method, so that it will return `data['disclaimer']` from the API, and inside `get_context_data` method, I have injected it inside context. That should do the trick, so that you will be able to see data in template with `{{ base }}`.

Comment: lovely this has worked a treat. This was a simple API test, would this method work when I start using a more complex API?

Comment: Yes absolutely. As long as you return value from 'call_geo_api' method