# inserting API data into html via django models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have created a function that allows me to loop through some data from an API I am using. I have tested this outside the Django model, and it works as intended.

Now I would like to put my code inside a Django model so I can use the data within an HTML page. I would like each of the values to be used within HTML tags, as I am creating a table of Jira tickets.

I have tried to work along with the following:

[Using APIs within Django and how to display the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57173335/using-apis-within-django-and-how-to-display-the-data)

for a previous test, which worked. It seems that I can't do it with the function I have created, listed below.

```py
def get_jira_tickets():
    jira_url = 'https://domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=CS'

    jira_r = requests.get(jira_url, auth=(
        'paulb@domain.com', 'API_KEY'))

    data = jira_r.json()

    client_name = '[client_name]'
    client_ID = '[client_ID]'

    for ticket in data['issues']:
        ticket_number = ticket['key']
        summary = ticket['fields']['summary']
        assignee = ticket['fields']['assignee']['name']
        status = ticket['fields']['status']['name']
        updated = dateutil.parser.parse(ticket['fields']['updated'])
        ticket_url = 'https://domain.atlassian.net/browse/' + ticket['key']
        client = ticket['fields']['customfield_10907'][0]['value']

        if status != 'Closed' and client_name in client and client_ID.upper() in client:

            ticket_dict = {
                'ticket_number': ticket_number,
                'summary': summary,
                'assignee': assignee,
                'status': status,
                'updated': updated,
                'url': ticket_url,
                'client_id': client
            }

            return ticket_dict
```

I would like to then use each element of the dict to insert into a table or HTML element to display the information. I would expect to use `ticket_dict[summary]` etc

Any ideas would be great.

This is how my view looks:

```py
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    '''
        This view will hold infomation from Pendo / Salesforce and Jira
        using their APIs to display the infomation.
    '''
    model = Post
    template_name = 'clients/post_detail.html'
    #  Salesforce API ---

    #  Jira Cloud API ---
    def jira_tickets(self):
        jira_url = 'https://domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=CS'

        jira_r = requests.get(jira_url, auth=(
            'paulb@domain.com', 'API_KEY'))

        data = jira_r.json()

        client_name = ['client_name']
        client_ID = ['client_ID']

        for ticket in data['issues']:
            ticket_number = ticket['key']
            summary = ticket['fields']['summary']
            assignee = ticket['fields']['assignee']['name']
            status = ticket['fields']['status']['name']
            updated = dateutil.parser.parse(ticket['fields']['updated'])
            ticket_url = 'https://domain.atlassian.net/browse/' + \
                ticket['key']
            client = ticket['fields']['customfield_10907'][0]['value']

            if status != 'Closed' and client_name in client and client_ID.upper() in client:

                ticket_dict = {
                    'ticket_number': ticket_number,
                    'summary': summary,
                    'assignee': assignee,
                    'status': status,
                    'updated': updated,
                    'url': ticket_url,
                    'client_id': client
                }

                return ticket_dict
```

Using the suggestion below, this is how I'd envision using the data:

```html
<table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Key</th>
                    <th scope="col">Summary</th>
                    <th scope="col">Assignee</th>
                    <th scope="col">Status</th>
                    <th scope="col">Updated</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for t in PostDetailView.jira_tickets %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ t.ticket_number }}</td>
                    <td><a href="{{ t.ticket_url }}">{{ t.summary }}</a></td>
                    <td>{{ t.assignee }}</td>
                    <td>{{ t.status }}</td>
                    <td>{{ t.updated }}</td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to make view returning you data put in context in HttpResponse object:
see this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial03/

simple but shows the point
and yeah, use Django template language in you html: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/language/

Comment: my view is a class not and out and out function. What would i be returning with the HttpResponse?

Comment: have you tried using TemplaeView scheme, just as described here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateView ?

Answer (score 0):

To display in your template, try it:

```
{% for t in view.get_jira_tickets %}
    {{ t.ticket_number }}
    {{ t.summary }}
    {{ t.assignee }}
    {{ t.status }}
    {{ t.updated }}
    {{ t.url }}
    {{ t.client_id }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: :( that didnt work I'm afraid. I have just added my whole model

Comment: Change: {% for t in PostDetailView.jira_tickets %} for the word "view" like the answer.

 {% for t in **view**.jira_tickets %}